# TensorFlow: Optimize for Inference a SavedModel exported by Estimator

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to optimize a saved graph for inference, so I can use it in Android.

My first attempt at using the optimize_for_inference script failed with

```
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message
```

So my question is whether the input/output nodes are wrong or the script cannot handle SavedModels (although it's the same extension as a frozen graph .pb)

Regarding the first: since with Estimators we provide input_fn instead of the data itself, which should be considered the input? The first tf operation on it? Like:

```
x = x_dict['gestures']

# Data input is a 1-D vector of x_dim * y_dim features ("pixels")
# Reshape to match format [Height x Width x Channel]
# Tensor input become 4-D: [Batch Size, Height, Width, Channel]
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, x_dim, y_dim, 1], name='input')

(...)

pred_probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='output')
```

BTW: if there is something different in loading a SavedModel in Android, I'd like to know too.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** There are good instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models which include an explaination of what to do with SavedModels. You can freeze your SavedModel using the [--input_saved_model_dir](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cfd0ea3bfb85d92cdb32760ea024f1e38618d717/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py#L362) to freeze_graph.py.

They're both protocol buffers (.pb), but unfortunately they're different messages (i.e. different file formats). Theoretically you could first extract a [MetaGraph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto) from the [SavedModel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto), then "freeze" the MetaGraph's GraphDef (move variables into constants), then run this script on the frozen GraphDef. In that case you'd want your input_fn to be just placeholders.

You could also add a plus one emoji on one of the ["SavedModel support for Android" Github issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12750). Medium-term we'd like to standardize on SavedModel; sorry you've run into this!

Comment: Thanks for replying. Added the +1 to the issue, since it's really a must-have if you're pushing for the SavedModel to be used.

Regarding the naming of input/output nodes: my input_fn is built using tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn to fill the feature dictionary and labels. No actual node here (and no way to name the possibly underlying placeholders right?), so I tried to use the first TF operation on x as the input (see question). Changed to "raw" TF for the time being (further issues in distribution) but was really enjoying the Estimator API and all that comes (or should) with it.

Comment: The intended strategy is that there's one input_fn for training (e.g. your numpy_input_fn), then when exporting the saved model you use an input_receiver_fn which either [accepts feeds explicitly](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn) (which sounds like what you're after) or [parses tf.Example messages](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn). This way you don't need to fiddle with the training input_fn to also work for serving.

Comment: Yes, to save the model I use  tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec) where feature_spec maps a tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, total_dimension]) to the same key used in the training input_fn. My issue was regarding the methods for optimizing_for_inference and such which always require the name of input and output nodes, which is not clear to me using the Estimator API (input_fn and model_fn) to build the network. Thanks for your comments anyway

Comment: @AllenLavoie : so if i understand correctly , there is no way to optimize the graph for inference if we use the saved_model serving graph ? Please let me know if there is a work around to freeze serving graph taking the Example proto as the input node for my inference graph ?

Comment: I think SavedModel works now with freeze_graph? See https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models and the ["input_saved_model_dir" flag for freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cfd0ea3bfb85d92cdb32760ea024f1e38618d717/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py#L362). I'll update the answer.