# Tensorflow - How to freeze a .pb from the SavedModel to be used for inference in TensorFlowInferenceInterface?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46287309/4535784), I can extract the `MetaGraph` from a `SavedModel`, then freeze the `MetaGraph`'s `GraphDef`, and THEN run the `freeze_graph.py` script on that `GraphDef` to get the `.pb` usable in Android. My question: how exactly do I extract the `MetaGraph` (and then its `GraphDef`)? Because `tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tag_constants.SERVING], <model_path>)` returns a `MetaGraphDef` instead of a `MetaGraph`.

Answer (score 2):

I just got it. Turns out, after removing the Tensorflow version I got from `conda` and replacing it with the one from `pip`, I could just do this:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

input_saved_model_dir = "F:/python_machine_learning_codes/estimator_exported_model/1509418513"
output_node_names = "softmax_tensor"
input_binary = False
input_saver_def_path = False
restore_op_name = None
filename_tensor_name = None
clear_devices = False
input_meta_graph = False
checkpoint_path = None
input_graph_filename = None
saved_model_tags = tag_constants.SERVING

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_filename, input_saver_def_path,
                            input_binary, checkpoint_path, output_node_names,
                              restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name,
                              output_graph_filename, clear_devices, "", "", "",
                              input_meta_graph, input_saved_model_dir,
                            saved_model_tags)
```

The one from `conda-forge` was incomplete, and even with the `pip` install, I had to copy the `freeze_graph.py` and the `saved_model_utils` from `tensorflow-master`. Also, the code from above is mostly copied  from the `freeze_graph_test.py`.

Comment: What tensorflow version are you using ?

Comment: IIRC, the version I was using when I had this problem was an old one that wasn't the most up-to-date version from pip.